# Use a standard single sql to group data (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Raw data with 2 columns:

```
0 33  
2 null   
0 44  
2 null  
2 null  
2 null  
0 55  
2 null  
2 null  
.....
```

Results I want:

```
2 33   
2 44  
2 44  
2 44  
2 55  
2 55  
....
```

Can I use a SQL statement to accomplish this? (return the rows with 2 only but fill with values come from the previous row that is 0), there could be many '2 null' between 0.

Comment: You are going to need to provide a third column which can be used to order things such that a given zero record can be associated with a group  of `NULL` records.

Comment: in what DBMS are you?

Comment: you can assume there is an Id column starting from 1

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Does column 1 contains 2 numbers 0 and 2 or it can contain anything?

Comment: column 1 only contains 0 or 2

Comment: Just to understand - you want to return only the rows that have null but return the first column and the "last not null" value of the second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way

```
with s as (
    select *
    from
    (values
        (1,0,33  ),
        (2,2,null),
        (3,0,44  ),
        (4,2,null),
        (5,2,null),
        (6,2,null),
        (7,0,55  ),
        (8,2,null),
        (9,2,null)
    ) T(id,a,b)
)
select s1.a, t.b
from s s1
cross apply ( 
    select top(1) s2.b 
    from s s2 
    where s2.id < s1.id and s2.b is not null and s2.a = 0
    order by s2.id desc ) t
where s1.a = 2
order by s1.id;
```

I use CROSS APPLY so the query may be easily extended to get other columns from  the relevant '0' row.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, select value for every row with null:

```
SELECT col2 FROM (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM your_tbl t WHERE t.ID < ID AND col2 IS NOT NULL);
```

Then write a condition for your table with that subquery:

```
SELECT col1, (
    SELECT col2 FROM your_tbl where id = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM your_tbl t 
    WHERE t.ID < tbl.ID AND col2 IS NOT NULL)) 
FROM your_tbl tbl WHERE col1 <> 0;
```